# How to rollback database with liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am using in my project liquibase for database migration.

I have this dependency in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and in application.properties this property:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelogs/changelog-master.xml
```

I am developing new task and I created few changesets with adding and renaming columns of tables, and now I found some mistake and I need change these changesets but at first I need rollback them.

Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: If you make a mistake in your changeSet, you write another changeSet that corrects the mistake. And both changeSets continue to live in you application.

Comment: This changeset was executed only on my local database, and I want revert changes without manually running scripts. Also if something wrong happened on production and we need rollback changes in database with version there should be some solution how to effectively did it.

Answer (score 2):

It is already mentioned in the comments, the preferred way to fix mistakes is by adding new change sets.
But if the changesets are not yet committed (they exist on your local machine only), it might be better to rollback and fix the changeset. And if the mistake would cause data loss, then you don't have another option than fixing it by changing the changeset before it reaches production even if it is already committed.

Liquibase has rollback features to support that:

See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html for the commands and options.
But it is possible only, if all changesets contain all required information to be able to rollback. See https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html for that. To minimize the required effort to have changesets with rollback information, you need to keep a few things in mind:

1. Prefer using Liquibase XML instead of sql scripts because with that, for all creates and adding of columns and constraints, Liquibase knows how to rollback without any extra information. For sql scripts, Liquibase can rollback only if you provide the required statements and that means you can make mistakes in there too.
2. Put every DDL action in a separate changeset to avoid an SQL failure in changesets causing the database ending up in an unclear state (half a changeset excuted).
3. Never remove a changeset entirely from the log if any database exists where it has been executed and not yet rollbacked. Removing a changeset makes rollback impossible on databases where it was already executed.

If a changeset was already committed and you need to change it, the validCheckSum tag (see https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) can be useful. But you should be very careful when using it.